# numpy.linalg.solve with right-hand side of more than three dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve an equation system with a 3x3 matrix `a` and a right hand side `b` of arbitrary shape `(3, ...)`. If `b` has one or two dimensions, `numpy.linalg.solve` does the trick. It breaks down for more dimensions though:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.random.rand(3, 3)

b = numpy.random.rand(3)
numpy.linalg.solve(a, b)  # okay

b = numpy.random.rand(3, 4)
numpy.linalg.solve(a, b)  # okay

b = numpy.random.rand(3, 4, 5)
numpy.linalg.solve(a, b)  # ERR
```

```
ValueError: solve: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core 
dimension 0, with gufunc signature (m,m),(m,n)->(m,n) (size 5 is 
different from 3)
```

I would have expected an output array `sol` of shape `(3, 4, 5)` with the solution corresponding to the right-hand side `b[:, i, j]` is `sol[:, i, j]`.

Any hint on how to best work around this?

Comment: What would that even mean? `numpy.linalg.solve` solves matrix equations, and `numpy.random.rand(3, 4, 5)` has too many dimensions to be a matrix.

Comment: I'd naturally expect an array of shape `(3, 4, 5)` as output; the solution with the right-hand side `b(:, i, j)` is `sol(:, i, j)`, much like in the other cases.

Comment: So you're thinking of the 2-dimensional `b` behavior as a sort of broadcasting of the 1-dimensional behavior, and expecting that to extend to more dimensions? That's not the design here; for one thing, NumPy broadcasting broadcasts over the left dimensions instead of the right. The design here is a matrix equation solver with a special case for treating a 1-dimensional `b` like a column matrix. You'll have to reshape your `b` into a matrix and reshape the solution back, like Warren Weckesser suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temporarily reshape `b` to `(3, 20)`, solve the linear system, and then reshape the resultant array to original shape of `b` (3, 4, 5):

```
In [34]: a = numpy.random.rand(3, 3)
In [35]: b = numpy.random.rand(3, 4, 5)

In [36]: x = numpy.linalg.solve(a, b.reshape(b.shape[0], -1)).reshape(b.shape)
```

OR

Swap the first axis of `b` with the second using [`np.swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html), solve the linear system, and then restore the axes:

```
In [58]: x = np.swapaxes(np.linalg.solve(a, np.swapaxes(b, 0, 1)), 0, 1)
```

---

Sanity Check:

```
In [38]: np.einsum('ij,jkl', a, x)
Out[38]: 
array([[[ 0.44859955,  0.22967928,  0.74336067,  0.47440575,  0.53798895],
        [ 0.80045696,  0.54138958,  0.89870834,  0.56862419,  0.28217437],
        [ 0.02093982,  0.78534718,  0.77208236,  0.41568151,  0.95100661],
        [ 0.03820421,  0.47067312,  0.71928294,  0.30852615,  0.64454321]],

       [[ 0.31757072,  0.30527186,  0.36768759,  0.95869289,  0.86601996],
        [ 0.60616508,  0.69927063,  0.53470332,  0.88906606,  0.76066344],
        [ 0.95411847,  0.51116677,  0.29338398,  0.04418815,  0.96210206],
        [ 0.23449429,  0.64159963,  0.7732404 ,  0.4314741 ,  0.81279619]],

       [[ 0.6399571 ,  0.57640652,  0.0186913 ,  0.66304489,  0.83372239],
        [ 0.28426522,  0.62367363,  0.37163699,  0.78217433,  0.90573787],
        [ 0.91066088,  0.06699638,  0.43079394,  0.00263537,  0.399102  ],
        [ 0.17711441,  0.48724858,  0.05526752,  0.34251648,  0.94059739]]])

In [39]: b
Out[39]: 
array([[[ 0.44859955,  0.22967928,  0.74336067,  0.47440575,  0.53798895],
        [ 0.80045696,  0.54138958,  0.89870834,  0.56862419,  0.28217437],
        [ 0.02093982,  0.78534718,  0.77208236,  0.41568151,  0.95100661],
        [ 0.03820421,  0.47067312,  0.71928294,  0.30852615,  0.64454321]],

       [[ 0.31757072,  0.30527186,  0.36768759,  0.95869289,  0.86601996],
        [ 0.60616508,  0.69927063,  0.53470332,  0.88906606,  0.76066344],
        [ 0.95411847,  0.51116677,  0.29338398,  0.04418815,  0.96210206],
        [ 0.23449429,  0.64159963,  0.7732404 ,  0.4314741 ,  0.81279619]],

       [[ 0.6399571 ,  0.57640652,  0.0186913 ,  0.66304489,  0.83372239],
        [ 0.28426522,  0.62367363,  0.37163699,  0.78217433,  0.90573787],
        [ 0.91066088,  0.06699638,  0.43079394,  0.00263537,  0.399102  ],
        [ 0.17711441,  0.48724858,  0.05526752,  0.34251648,  0.94059739]]])
```

Use [`np.allclose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) so that you don't have to manually going through the numbers and check, particularly for large arrays:

```
In [32]: b_ = np.einsum('ij,jkl', a, x)

In [33]: np.allclose(b, b_)
Out[33]: True
```

Comment: @kmario23, thanks, I was thinking about coming back and doing the same thing!

Comment: The beauty of `np.einsum()` ;) `np.matmul` fails when it sees 2D and 3D combo!
I have to resort to same trick you used:
`np.matmul(a, x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)).reshape(x.shape)`

Comment: @kmario23 hello, you seem to know a lot about this. could you please help me with my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152952/finding-unknown-values-in-python/58153044#58153044

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser could you please take a look at my question. I am facing a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152952/finding-unknown-values-in-python/58153044#58153044

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) clearly states:

> a : (..., M, M) array_like
>
> Coefficient matrix.
>
> b : {(..., M,), (..., M, K)}, array_like
>
> Ordinate or “dependent variable” values.

So the before last dimension must be the same as the last two dimensions of `a` (**M**). Other than that it behaves as you expect - more dimensions are possible, returning a result with the same dimension as `B`. This way the solution of `Ax=B` is naturally calculated, and the dimensions automatically converted - just solving many systems of equations with solution of dimension (M,K), and embedding them in the outer dimensions. In your case having `3` at the beginning and not in the middle is confusing the algorithm. Example with 3 dimensions;

```
>>> a=np.random.rand(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> b=np.random.rand(12).reshape(2,3,2)
>>> np.linalg.solve(a,b)
array([[[-0.63673083,  0.57508091],
        [ 0.87653408,  0.46092677],
        [ 0.61128222, -0.19641607]],

       [[-0.91645601,  1.30939652],
        [ 0.83591936, -0.17006344],
        [ 0.19086912,  0.29082206]]])
```