# numpy.linalg.solve with multiple dependent right-hand side

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve an equation system like Ax=b with full rank matrix A and right-hand side b including two columns for two different systems with the same left side. (Ax=b1, Ax=b2, b=concatenate((b1, b2), axis=1)). The point is that we have the same A for two systems. Therefore we should be able to use info from the first system for the second i.e the inverse of A.

numpy.linalg.solve easily solves this system if the columns of b are independent that is not my case. In my case, the second column of b depends on the solution of the first system.

I have tried to factorize matrix A and use this factorization to solve two systems. But, it is not efficient at all. Considering A is not symmetric I have used RQ and LU decomposition.

```
from scipy.linalg import lu
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import solve_triangular
def qr_solver(a, b):
   q, r = np.linalg.qr(a)
   z = solve_triangular(r, b, lower=False)
   ans = np.dot(q.T, z)
   return ans
def plu_solver(a, b):
   per, l, u = lu(kkt_matrix)
   z = np.dot(per.T , b)
   x = solve_triangular(l, z, lower=True)
   ans = solve_triangular(u, x)
   return ans
```

Comment: Is anything wrong with this question? Do we have LAPACK module that can be used here ?

Comment: What's you question?  You are the one who knows how to modify `b2`.  Can't you just do a `solve`, create the new `b` and repeat?

Comment: Considering the time for solving two systems it is going to increase the total time by factor two! when you have the same left side it is more rational to use the first factorization for the second equation too.

Comment: The point here is that we have the same A for two systems and different b. Numpy solves these systems efficiently if the left sides are independent. But in my case, the 'b' of the second equation depends on the answer to the first system. Is it clear now?

Comment: For more clarity look at this equation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48387261/numpy-linalg-solve-with-right-hand-side-of-more-than-three-dimensions

Comment: A standard method is the one you proposed: decompose `A` into factors that can be reused to efficiently solve `Ax = b` repeatedly for different `b`.  You say *"But, it is not efficient at all."*  How did you measure this?  Show the code that you say is not efficient.  (Currently, you show the call `per, l, u = lu(A)`, but you don't show how you use the result to solve `Ax = b1` and `Ax = b2`.)

Comment: I have added that part to my question. And for the measurement simply I compared the time of solving the system two times with numpy and solving using the factorization.

Comment: It has happened to me here again! When they cannot answer the question they give you a negative score :)))) I think we should ask questions that are easy to answer to get points.

Answer (score 2):

scipy exposes `lu_factor` and `lu_solve` for this sort of problem:

```
from scipy.linalg import lu_factor, lu_solve

# Solving Ax = b1, Ay = f(x) with same A

lu, pivot = lu_factor(A)
x = lu_solve((lu, pivot), b1)
b2 = f(x)
y = lu_solve((lu, pivot), b2)
```

So if the RHS vectors are not linearly independent (implicit Runge-Kutta schemes are a good example), you can factorize the LHS once, and re-use it to solve as often as required.

Comment: I just tried to implement and compare your nice piece of code. It seems to be working really good.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to just program what 'Talonmies' stated:

```
    from scipy.linalg import lu_factor, lu_solve
    from scipy.linalg import cho_factor
    from scipy.linalg import solve
    import numpy as np
    import time
    # Solving Ax = b1, Ay = f(x) with same A
    A = np.random.normal(1, 10, (2000, 2000))
    b1 = np.random.normal(1, 10, (2000, 1))
    b2 = np.random.normal(1, 10, (2000, 1))
    start = time.time()
    lu, pivot = lu_factor(A)
    x = lu_solve((lu, pivot), b1)
    y = lu_solve((lu, pivot), b2)
    end = time.time()
    time_factorization = start-end
    start = time.time()
    x = np.linalg.solve(A, b1)
    y = np.linalg.solve(A, b1)
   end = time.time()
   time_solve = start-end
   print('time_factorization:', time_factorization, 'time_solve:', time_solve)
```

and here the results:
time_factorization: 0.6500372886657715 
time_solve: 0.9420537948608398

It seems that this kind of factorization(getting lu and pivots) is really efficient.